# Why won't Elixir compiler raise warnings on some "non-matchable" functions?

Tags: elixir

Elixir raises warnings if you write a code like this inside a module:

```
def func(_) do
  true
end

def func(m) when is_integer(m) do
  false
end
```

as: `warning: this clause cannot match because a previous clause at line 1 always matches`

This is very helpful, especially when having many many functions in a module.
But when writing codes like below:

```
def func(n) when is_integer(n) do
  true
end

def func(m) when is_integer(m) do
  false
end
```

this will not raise any warnings.
Why won't this, or am I misunderstanding something? (like either can match in some situations?)

Comment: I think the compiler builds a dispatch tree for the function. In the first case it easy to analyze against the tree that only the first entry will get dispatched. In the second case, the analyzer will needs to compare mathematically the expressions in the guard clauses and see if they are overlap. Like `m > 0` cover `m > 1`. I don't think that functionally is build in the analyzer for that. But that is just my thought. 
https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/issues/1215

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case you actually have a function clause that matches any thing when passed one argument.  It is obvious at that point that any other one-arity clauses of that function will be superfluous.

In the second case, the system sees two one-arity functions with guard clauses.  It doesn't perform an exhaustive static analysis to figure out that the guard clauses are the same... guard clause expressions can be complex and I suspect it would be a challenge to ensure they cover the same ground.  So all the compiler can tell is that the two functions MIGHT match different cases and doesn't issue a warning.